# Visual Studio Code GitHub account

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, angular-cli

I have a Visual Studio Code project for an Angular2 app created using AngularCli (webpack version).  Out of the box, AngularCli will generate a new project for you and check it into Git.  How do you know which GitHub account it's using?  I cannot find any information in Visual Studio as to what GitHub account is controlling the code history.  I can make changes to the code and check it in using Visual Studio Code's embedded Git functionality.  I've logged into GitHub using my account, but I do not see this new project.  Where do you find information on what GitHub account either AngualrCli and/or Visual Studio Code is using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do you know which GitHub account it's using?

It doesn't need to use any github account to create a git repo. It's just calling `git init`, followed by some `git add`/`git commit` commands. You can do those without github credentials. After the tool does its job, you have a fully-functional local git repo.

You only need github account when you try to push code to github, which you did not yet do, I assume. You **don't** need github credentials to work with local repository (view history, add new commits, branch, merge, etc.)

Comment: Ahhhhh, yes.  It makes sense now.  I couldn't figure it out at 1am.  Thanks for the help.